# Cannot create an instance of class .LoginViewModel when launching the app

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

when I run the RegistrationFrame2() composable as a direct content , it works with no problems

```
@Composable
fun RegistrationFrame2() {

val context = LocalContext.current
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val tabViewModel = viewModel<TabRowViewModel>()
val loginViewModel = viewModel<LoginViewModel>()
val signupViewModel = viewModel<SignupViewModel>()
val initialText = tabViewModel.getRegistrationInitialText(context)
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = tabViewModel.scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(hostState = tabViewModel.scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) },
    modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
) {

    BoxWithConstraints(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(it)
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember {
                    MutableInteractionSource()
                }
            ) {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
    ) {
        val boxScope = this

        RegistrationHeaderWidget(screenHeight = boxScope.maxHeight)
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                top = boxScope.maxHeight.times(0.217f),
                start = 17.dp,
                end = 17.dp
            )
        ) {

            Text(
                text = initialText,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp, top = 10.dp)
                    .animateContentSize(
                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 350)
                    ),
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    color = MaterialTheme.digitalColors.textBlackColor
                )
            )

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .animateContentSize(
                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250)
                    )

            ) {
                Crossfade(
                    targetState = tabViewModel.currentIndex(),
                    animationSpec = tween(150),
                ) { currentIndex ->
                    if (currentIndex == 0) {
                        LoginPage()
                    } else {
                        RegistrationPage()
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(15.dp))
            if (loginViewModel.state().isLoading || signupViewModel.state().isLoading) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.primaryColor)
                    )
                }
            } else {
                val onRegistrationSubmit = remember<(Context, ScaffoldState) -> Unit> {
                    { context, scaffoldState ->
                        if (tabViewModel.currentIndex() == 0) {
                            loginViewModel.login(context, scaffoldState)
                        } else {
                            signupViewModel.validateAndSignup(context, scaffoldState)
                        }
                    }
                }

                val regBtnText = if (tabViewModel.currentIndex() == 0) R.string.loginSubmitButton else R.string.signupSubmitButton
                RegistrationSubmitButton(
                    textResourceId = regBtnText,
                    onClick = onRegistrationSubmit
                )
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            RegistrationFooterText(
                enabled = !loginViewModel.state().isLoading && !signupViewModel.state().isLoading
            )
        }

    }

}
  }
```

But When I run it as a child inside a navHost and set it as a start destination ,

I get this error messages

```
    Process: com.example.application_digital, PID: 5298
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class 
    com.example.application_digital.features.registration.presentation.
    login.view_models.LoginViewModel

    
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
     java.lang.Class<com.example.application_digital.features.
     registration.presentation.login.view_models.LoginViewModel> 
     has no zero argument constructor
```

this is the navhost composable

```
@Composable
fun RootNavigator(navController: NavHostController) {

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = RootNavigatorRoutes.RegistrationPage.route,
)
{
    composable(
        route = RootNavigatorRoutes.RegistrationPage.route,
    ) {
        RegistrationFrame2()
    }

    composable(route = RootNavigatorRoutes.HomePage.route) {
        HomePageFrame()
    }


    composable(route = RootNavigatorRoutes.ForgotPasswordPage.route) {
        throw Exception("Unimplemented Route yet")
    }

    composable(route = RootNavigatorRoutes.OTPVerificationPage.route) {
        throw Exception("Unimplemented Route yet")
    }
}
```

}

LoginViewModel code

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val phoneValidator: PhoneValidator,
   private val passwordValidator: PasswordValidator,
   private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase,

) :
    BaseViewModel() {

  private var loginState by mutableStateOf(LoginState())

  fun state(): LoginState = loginState

  fun dispatch(event: SignupEvent) {

    when (event) {
        is SignupEvent.PhoneNumberChanged -> {
            loginState = loginState.copy(
                phoneNumber = event.phoneNumber,
                phoneNumberErrorMessage = null,
            )
        }
        is SignupEvent.PasswordChanged -> {
            loginState = loginState.copy(
                password = event.password,
                passwordErrorMessage = null,
            )
        }

        is KeepMeLoggedInEvent -> {
            loginState = loginState.copy(
                keepMeLoggedIn = event.keepMeLoggedIn
            )
        }

        is SignupEvent.ShowPassword -> {
            loginState = loginState.copy(
                showPassword = event.visible
            )
        }

        else -> {}
      }

   }


  fun onPhoneNumberChanged(update: String) {

    val event = SignupEvent.PhoneNumberChanged(update)
    dispatch(event)
 }

  fun onPasswordChanged(update: String) {
    val event = SignupEvent.PasswordChanged(update)
    dispatch(event)

 }

  private fun setIsLoadingTo(update: Boolean) {
     if (loginState.isLoading != update) {
         loginState = loginState.copy(isLoading = update)
      }
 }


    private fun getProperPasswordErrorMessage(errorMessages: 
   List<Int>): Int? {
      if (errorMessages.isEmpty()) {
        return null
      }

      if (loginState.password.isEmpty()) {
        return R.string.passwordIsRequired
     }
      return R.string.invalidPassword

}

private fun validate(): Boolean {

    val phoneErrorMessage = 
         phoneValidator.validate(loginState.phoneNumber)
    val passwordErrorMessage = 
       passwordValidator.validate(loginState.password)


    loginState = loginState.copy(
        phoneNumberErrorMessage = if (phoneErrorMessage.isEmpty()) 
        null else phoneErrorMessage.first(),
        passwordErrorMessage = 
       getProperPasswordErrorMessage(passwordErrorMessage)
    )

    val noPasswordError = loginState.passwordErrorMessage == null
    val noPhoneNumberError = loginState.phoneNumberErrorMessage == 
   null

    return noPasswordError && noPhoneNumberError
}


fun login(context: Context, scaffoldState: ScaffoldState) {

    val valid = validate()
    Log.d("TT", "login: ")
    if (!valid) {
        Log.d("TT", "inside if: ")
        return
    }
    Log.d("TT", "beyond if: ")
    val payload = LoginPayload(
        phoneNumber = loginState.phoneNumber,
        password = loginState.password,
    )
    viewModelScope.launch {
        setIsLoadingTo(true)
        val response = loginUseCase.execute(payload)
        setIsLoadingTo(false)
        if (response.hasError()) {
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = 
         context.getString(response.errorMessage!!))
            return@launch
        }
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = 
       "process done successfully")
       }

   }


 }
```

Comment: LoginViewModel does it have constructor with params?

Comment: @Yurii I have just updated the question with the loginViewModel code , you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide factory to you ViewModel like here:
Documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories

```kotlin
viewModel: LoginViewModel= viewModel(  
        factory = LoginViewModelFactory(param1, param2)  
    )
```

For hilt:

```kotlin
viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>()
```

Comment: then why it works when it alone and does not work when being within a navhost ??

Comment: Try hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>() in NavHost

Comment: @Yurri 
that true, the solution was just to use hiltViewmodel instead of viewModel within the the navhost, thank you bro

Comment: Welcome, mark my answer as resolved issue.